# Unable to get missing lines & branches in nose2

Tags: python-3.x, nose2

I'm trying to get my tests to report missing lines and branches. I've configured nose2 and coverage to produce line and branch coverage, and as far as I can tell I have set the coverage config correctly to give me the missing lines and branches. However I can't get coverage to give me missing column when run under nose2, but I can if I run it directly.

---

Consider the following setup in my project directory.

```
my_module/
    __init__.py
    main.py
tests/
    test_a_thing.py
unittest.cfg
.coveragerc
```

contents of .coveragerc

```
[run]
branch = True

[report]
show_missing = True
```

contents of unittest.cfg

```
[coverage]
always-on = True
coverage = my_module
coverage-config = .coveragerc
```

the output of my nose2 command

```
(example_venv) andy@batman[11:30:53]:/space/test_example$ python -m nose2 -c unittest.cfg --no-user-config
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

OK
----------- coverage: platform linux, python 3.5.2-final-0 -----------
Name                    Stmts   Miss Branch BrPart  Cover
---------------------------------------------------------
my_module/__init__.py       0      0      0      0   100%
my_module/main.py           4      1      2      1    67%
---------------------------------------------------------
TOTAL                       4      1      2      1    67%
```

As you can see, it has given me `Branch` cover, but not told me the missing branches.

If I simply run `coverage report` (on the produced `.coverage` file that is left behind after running nose)

```
(example_venv) andy@batman[11:34:15]:/space/test_example$ coverage report
Name                    Stmts   Miss Branch BrPart  Cover   Missing
-------------------------------------------------------------------
my_module/__init__.py       0      0      0      0   100%
my_module/main.py           4      1      2      1    67%   3, 2->3
-------------------------------------------------------------------
TOTAL                       4      1      2      1    67%
```

You can see that coverage has given me the missing branches.

---

I can tell that `coverage` is picking up the `.coveragerc` when run under `nose2`, because if I remove the `branch = True` line under the `[run]` section in `.coveragerc`, then the branch coverage stats disappear from the report when run under `nose`.

---

Am I missing something extra I'm supposed to have done to get this `show_missing` config to get passed to `coverage` when it is run under `nose2`?

versions installed

```
cov-core==1.15.0
coverage==4.3.4
nose2==0.6.5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tl;dr - have to add `coverage-report = term-missing` to the `[coverage]` section in the `unittest.cfg` (or other `--config [CONFIG], -c [CONFIG]` file) for `nose2`. In order for `Cov-Core` to pass `show_missing = True` to `coverage`

---

Longer explanation:

When running `coverage report` on the command-line, `show_missing` is passed into `coverage.coverage()`* as `None` unless overridden in the command line arguments.

However `nose2` uses `cov-core`, which will pass `show_missing` to `coverage.coverage()`* in `cov_core.CovController.summary()` as either `True` or `False`. Based upon the following logic:

```
if 'term' in self.cov_report or 'term-missing' in self.cov_report:
    show_missing = 'term-missing' in self.cov_report
    self.cov.report(show_missing=show_missing, ignore_errors=True, file=stream)
```

`cov_report` is that `coverage-report` config set in `nose2`.

So this is my confusion because I was trying to use `coverage`'s configs to yield missing lines/branches (when doing a report to term, there's an extra flag for `show_missing`), when `Cov-Core` treats them as separate reports (either report `term` to get plain coverage, or `term-missing` to get plain coverage + missing lines).

So don't let yourself be bitten by this bit of coverage behaviour `Cov-Core` has decided to override, when most other bits (include/exclude branch coverage for one) are still driven by `coverage`'s configs.

---

<sub>*coverage.coverage() is a backwards compatability tweak, and is actually an import (in coverage/__init__.py) for coverage.control.Coverage()</sub>